# Check occurence of two consecutive XML tag in Unix Shell

Tags: xml, shell, awk, grep, ksh

I have the following XML File:

```
<PARENT_TAG>
    <CHILD_TAG>
        <DETAIL_1_TAG></DETAIL_1_TAG>
        <DETAIL_2_TAG></DETAIL_2_TAG>
        <DETAIL_3_TAG></DETAIL_3_TAG>
        <DETAIL_4_TAG></DETAIL_4_TAG>
    </CHILD_TAG>
</PARENT_TAG>
```

which can be formatted even as

```
<PARENT_TAG><CHILD_TAG><DETAIL_1_TAG> ...  </CHILD_TAG></PARENT_TAG>
```

I would like to extract the name of the xml tag following  using grep,awk,sed.
In this case, I would extract "CHILD_TAG".

Comment: Not clear what is your expected output. Also, parsing a xml with awk/sed is not the best idea: consider using a proper xml parser.

Comment: `extract the name of the xml tag following` what? `<PARENT_TAG>`? Does that block occur once or many times in your input file? Can `<PARENT_TAG>` appear in other contexts where you don't want to extract the tag that follows it? Can it have any associated attributes within the `<...>`? If any of that or any other variances can happen then modify your sample input to show that and in any case post your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all in one line by this:

```
awk '$1=$1' ORS="" file
<PARENT_TAG><CHILD_TAG><DETAIL_1_TAG></DETAIL_1_TAG><DETAIL_2_TAG></DETAIL_2_TAG><DETAIL_3_TAG></DETAIL_3_TAG><DETAIL_4_TAG></DETAIL_4_TAG></CHILD_TAG></PARENT_TAG>
```

But if you have more lines, you need to set a start and end pattern.

Here is another example:

```
cat file
test
<PARENT_TAG>
    <CHILD_TAG>
        <DETAIL_1_TAG></DETAIL_1_TAG>
        <DETAIL_2_TAG></DETAIL_2_TAG>
        <DETAIL_3_TAG></DETAIL_3_TAG>
        <DETAIL_4_TAG></DETAIL_4_TAG>
    </CHILD_TAG>
</PARENT_TAG>
more data
```

```
awk '/<PARENT/ {f=1} /<\/PARENT/ {f=0} {printf "%s%s",$1,(f?"":RS)}'
test
<PARENT_TAG><CHILD_TAG><DETAIL_1_TAG></DETAIL_1_TAG><DETAIL_2_TAG></DETAIL_2_TAG><DETAIL_3_TAG></DETAIL_3_TAG><DETAIL_4_TAG></DETAIL_4_TAG></CHILD_TAG></PARENT_TAG>
more
```

This removes newline only within `PARENT`tag.